Who became an oligarch after the collapse of the USSR
I quickly read the biographies and history of famous Russian oligarchs (Chubais and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semibankirschina). This is a small sample, but I got the impression that the “tidbit” during perestroika was grabbed by those who were initially market-minded. In connection with these questions:

Why didn’t the top government of the USSR, knowing where everything was going, prepare the ground for their good life (without taking into account the country's population)? For example, given the current privatization policy, they could privatize factories for themselves.
What contributed to the current rich people who appeared after the collapse of the USSR to become rich?
Capitalism postulates that everyone can become rich. Isn't this a confirmation of the theory? Or is it just survivorship bias?
Is it possible to become a large corporation from scratch without government assistance or political upheavals?

If I am relying on incorrect premises somewhere, please point them out.

Welcome to Politics.SE! This is asking four separate questions at once; you need to narrow this down to just one.

#4 is the only question I can imagine being developed to fit on this site. Others might belong on History or Economics SE but not here.

I'd narrow it down to just 1. and 2. - these BTW are unsolved questions to which there is no consensus known to me.

Does capitalism postulate that everyone can become rich or it is more restrictive in that any given person can get rich? Where is the wealth coming from to ensure that everyone is a billionaire?

Very good questions. Even though they are related please open a new question for every single question that you have. That was answers can concentrate on answering the same single questions.

why was this closed? censorship? its all good q's

@max The close reason is very clear: it was closed because it's asking four questions at once. They may well be good questions individually, but you can't ask all of them at the same time.

This whole "multiple questions" objection seems unjustified to me.  The title says it all:  "who became rich and how did they do it?"  It's not uncommon to take a simple question and qualify it with some of the specifics the OP is asking about.  Yes, some of the subquestions here veer off subject, but the gist can be answered easily enough.  There is plenty of info on who got what and how they got it.  And this Q is not necessarily consigned to SE.History because it very much impacts how Russia behaves externally and internally even today.  Suggestions for edits are justified but not closure.

An analogy would be someone asking about the background of the Republican Southern Strategy shift in the early 70s. Sure, it seems historical enough, and it is even older than asking about the post-Soviet transition, but it explains much of current US politics. Consequently we keep those questions. My own edit suggestion is to mostly limit the subquestions to #2: What contributed to the current rich people who appeared after the collapse of the USSR to become rich? which fits pretty well with the title

There were plenty of would-be oligarchs that didn't make it because their competitors ruined them or killed them. Survivorship is a big factor.

"Capitalism postulates that everyone can become rich." Capitalism is not an ideology as such, so it doesn't postulate anything of the sort. Almost no political party self-labels 'capitalist'. You're probably [mis]remembering some similar phrases advanced by [some] politicians like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_rising_tide_lifts_all_boats And what the 'tide' was varied with the politician. For some it was some kind of Keynesianism [gov't spending in infrastructure etc.], for others tax cuts on the rich, and so on.

Putin's People goes into this at length.  There are different timelines to be considered and different actors for each.
Phase 1.  In the beginning the KGB was somewhat of a driver for reform and economic liberalization.  Motivation:  a perception doctrinal Communism economic management was not keeping up with the West.  Additionally, they wanted to park money abroad in case Communism fell.  This started a tradition of money secreted abroad.  Sometimes to facilitate disguised donations to Communist parties, like the Italian one.
The easy way to make money was to buy resources (say oil) at the - low - Soviet internal price and sell them abroad at the - much higher - world market prices.
Anyone who was a go-getter and got on with the KGB could benefit.  This was the case with Khodorkovsky who started out organizing raves.

The introduction of perestroika enabled Khodorkovsky to use his connections within the communist structures to gain a foothold in the developing free market. With the help of some powerful people, he started his business activities under the cover of Komsomol. Friendship with another Komsomol leader, Alexey Golubovich, had a significant impact on his growing success, since Golubovich's parents held top positions in Gosbank, the State Bank of the USSR.[20] Among the businesses in which Khodorkovsky "tried his hand" were "importing personal computers and, according to some sources, counterfeit alcohol." In addition, he "ventured into finance, devising ways to squeeze cash out of the Soviet planned-economy behemoth

A third way money was made was to leverage fees and bribes out of big Western companies that wanted to do business in Russia.

All over the word – from Bangladesh, Vietnam, Russia, and Mexico to Greece, Norway Iraq and Nigeria – Siemens paid bribes to government officials and civil servants. The magnitude of the bribery system was widespread.

Last, in a system where you an overvalued official exchange rate on a non-convertible currency, like the Soviet rubles, anyone with ready access to hard currency has outsized opportunities, compared to a more normal economy.
When it comes to operations more directly run by the KGB, disguising money is a goal, for national security reasons.  However, that murkiness also brought a "petty cash" culture, where the money is still the state's but is well understood to be usable for personal expenses as well.

Second phase, after Communism fell, was the Jeffrey Sachs inspired mass privatization, carried out by Chubais.  Instead of the state owning all those loss-making SEOs let's give out shares to the people.  That coincided with some really hard times in Russia and people had little to eat.  They would easily trade essentially worthless shares for bread to eat.  Anyone who had sufficient cash flow - and connections to deal with permits - snarfed up stuff at bargain prices.  By this point, the security services are losing control.
(NPR)How 'shock therapy' created Russian oligarchs and paved the path for Putin

Privatization was conducted in two waves. The first wave, which began in October 1992, had at least the veneer of being a fair and open process. Russia issued 148 million "privatization checks," or vouchers, to Russian citizens. These vouchers could be freely sold or traded. They could then be used to buy shares of state enterprises going private at public auctions around the nation. It was like the former Soviet Union was holding the world's largest garage sale and vouchers were the tickets to shop.


The people on their way to becoming Russia's first class of oligarchs scoured the nation, trying to buy as many vouchers as they could. Many of the oligarchs had come from nothing. They had initially gotten rich — but not quite buy-superyachts rich just yet — by hustling in the black market or through legitimate businesses when the Soviet Union first allowed private entrepreneurship in the late 1980s (note: Phase 1). For example, Roman Abramovich made his first pot of money selling rubber ducks and other random objects to Russians out of his Moscow apartment (seriously). He was also a mechanic. By the time privatization began, many soon-to-be oligarchs owned banks and had enough money to buy lots of vouchers.

Along this time too it became lucrative to syphon off such Western aid and assistance as was provided to Russia.  Much of the goods provided to the Leningrad region - while Putin was 2nd in command under its mayor - never reached the population.

Third phase - 1995-1996 - the Russian government runs out of money  and oligarchs helpfully loan them some, with state companies as collateral.  Conveniently the state could not always repay them and the state companies went out for auction.  Often in slimy circumstances - "Putin's People" cites one case where an auction in Siberia essentially had the town roads shut down so that only the favored bidders could make it.  The security services are sidelined and remaining state assets are purchased at very large discounts.
Loan for shares

In 1995, facing severe fiscal deficit and in desperate need of funds for the 1996 presidential elections, the government of Boris Yeltsin adopted a "loans-for-shares" scheme proposed by banker Vladimir Potanin and endorsed by Chubais, then a deputy prime minister, whereby some of the largest state industrial assets (including state-owned shares in Norilsk Nickel, Yukos, Lukoil, Sibneft, Surgutneftegas, Novolipetsk Steel, and Mechel) were leased through auctions for money lent by commercial banks to the government. The auctions were rigged and lacked competition, being largely controlled by favored insiders with political connections or used for the benefit of the commercial banks themselves.4 As neither the loans nor the leased enterprises were returned in time, this effectively became a form of selling, or privatizing, state assets at very low prices.


1999-2000 Putin takes over.  At this point, things start to turn against the oligarchs.  At first, this starts with TV channels.
Gusinsky was an oligarch who owned NTV, an independent TV channel.  I think he may have tried to either become political, or to back another politician as an alternative to Putin.  In any case, he was nosing around too much around rumors of false flag terrorist attacks to justify the Second Chechnya War.  His channel gets expropriated.
Another case is Berezovsky's ORT:

However, on 31 May, Berezovsky sharply attacked the constitutional reform proposed by the president, which would give the Kremlin the right to dismiss elected governors.[100] On 17 July 2000, Berezovsky resigned from the Duma, saying he "did not want to be involved in the country's ruin and the restoration of an authoritarian regime".[101] In August, Berezovsky's media attacked Putin for the way he handled the sinking of the Kursk submarine, blaming the death of 118 sailors on the Kremlin's reluctance to accept foreign help.[102] In September, Berezovsky alleged that the Kremlin had attempted to expropriate his shares in ORT and announced that he would put his stake into a trust to be controlled by prominent intellectuals.[103]

Note that Putin had been assisted to power by Berenovsky.

He was quick to grasp the opportunities to make money offered by perestroika, rapidly followed by the collapse of the Soviet Union and the new world of capitalism.


Together with his commercial partner, Badri Patarkatsishvili, Berezovsky went into the car business in 1989, selling Soviet-made models (phase 1). By 1994, he wasrich enough for someone to try to murder him with a car bomb that killed his driver. But Berezovsky's ambitions were also political. In 1994, he acquired the television channel ORT, then used it as a weapon to secure Boris Yeltsin's election in 1996 against the communists.


They dispatched Berezovsky to offer the job to Putin – who became prime minister in the summer of 1999, succeeding Yeltsin as acting president six months later.


Berezovsky had reckoned that his friend would be a pliable successor – and that he, the ultimate Kremlin insider, would continue to pull the strings. It quickly became apparent that Putin had his own vision of Russia: a darker, less democratic place, in which the country's spy agencies would play a vanguard role, and with Putin unequivocally in charge.

Khodorovsky's Yukos - acquired through doubtless shady means - gets expropriated in 2003:

Khodorkovsky, who used to be Russia's richest man, was arrested at gunpoint in 2003 and convicted of theft and tax evasion in 2005. Yukos, once worth $40 billion, was broken up and nationalized, with most assets handed to Rosneft , an energy giant run by an ally of Putin.

Note who gets the ca$h cows now:  friends of Putin.  Khodorovsky  wasn't an angel:  several of his business opponents met untimely ends, but his main error was to start voicing political views and ambitions.
From now on, oligarchs increasingly operate at the sufferance of the Kremlin.

Fourth phase.  No more of this robbery by private interests.  Under Putin, the state apparatus, under the KGB successor services, is back in control.  Take Rosneft for example, which got awarded the remnants of Yukos.  Sure, running it may be very lucrative for those sitting at the top.  But it seen to be firmly under state control, unlike Yukos.
So the uncontrolled oligarch phase can officially be stated to be over.
Such concessions are lucrative enough in any case that Rotenberg who runs Stroygazmontzsh, much smaller than Rosneft can afford to build a $350M+ palace on the Black Sea.
And what is Rotenberg's particular talent in business?

He is a close confidant, business partner, and childhood friend of president Vladimir Putin.  (Note:  and judo partner)

In many cases, who is investing what is murky.  That's how a - doubtless very talented - cellist friend of Putin's had $400M to his name in the Panama Papers leaks.

This question is borderline SE.History, SE.Politics.  However, consider that the world is still being affected by the unwinding of the Soviet Union and that Putin - in as far as he has any actual mandate from the his "electorate" - is being assessed by Russians in light of how he has "corrected" those excesses.  Excesses that Russian politicians are fond of blaming the West for.
Note again the NPR title:  How 'shock therapy' created Russian oligarchs and paved the path for Putin

Your first source argues from the end, Putin seizing power. But that is only the last phase. My impression is that the role of the KGB and its successors is overstated. Especially for the first stage, it must be noted that a substantial black market was already well established during the Brezhnev years, and fighting corruption was not really his priority.

@ccprog I mostly answered this from a book whose whole thesis has to do with Putin.  But it does cover oligarchs at length.  Yes, there was an organized crime aspect to the oligarchs, in a perhaps uniquely Russian fashion.  But it was not their "core competence", they had to have official standing to be in charge of such huge legitimate, businesses.  In order to visibly sell oil in mass quantities abroad, esp. pre-1991-ish you had to have a right to purchase it and a right to export it.  And if you were a listed oil company you had to have a modicum of legitimacy to go with that.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I agree with that, but that does not mean it had to pass muster by the KGB. Of the few Brezhnev-era corruption scandals that came to light and are listed here, two were covered by ministries, and one by a regional government. And the fact that one of the few initiatives by Yuri Andropov was an anti-corruption campaign might be seen as a sign he was not happy with the influence the KGB had during his tenure as its director.

@ccprog Please note that this claim of close involvement by the KGB during phase 1 isn't mine, it is very much the book's.  And he does spend a lot of time documenting how Soviet money was sloshing around in the 80s and early 90s.  Anti-corruption campaigns can have many motivations, looks at Xi Jinping's.  In any case, phase 1 still runs the same - well-connected people get some form of official cover - be it KGB, be it Comm. Party officials - to skim off Soviet-vs-World price differentials: see enabled K. to use his connections within the communist... above.  Not just gangster work.


Why didn’t the top government of the USSR, knowing where everything was going, prepare the ground for their good life (without taking into account the country's population)? For example, given the current privatization policy, they could privatize factories for themselves.

One potentially good answer is that Gorbachev was deposed and therefore the power was yanked from under him and the remaining Politburo members.
He was replaced with Yeltsin who along with his post-nuclear family has amassed great amount of economic power in the 90's.
One can imagine that if Gorbachev was able to stay in power, the existing USSR top government will be able to retain much more stuff. One thing Yeltsin could be doing mid-90s. is ensuring his opponents from USSR top government do not grow powerful by not letting them take advantage.
If we look around, there are both countries whose leadership inherited it from Soviet times, such as Aliyev's Azerbaijan, and ones where the power was seized from pre-independence leadership, such as Lukashenko's Belarus.

What contributed to the current rich people who appeared after the collapse of the USSR to become rich?

That's a great question to which I do not know coherent answers. It is postulated that a lot of critical industries were handed out via loans for shares to avoid them being bought out by overseas capital - but one may also notice that a lot of that capital ended out in the hands of apparent ethnic minorities. One reason for the latter might be that USSR ethnic outskirts had greater economical freedom than its core regions, so they both had some initial capital as well as skills to make it work. But, as I've noticed, this is only some conjectures for an "I don't know".

Capitalism postulates that everyone can become rich. Isn't this a confirmation of the theory? Or is it just survivorship bias?

That is indeed true to some extent. I personally know some rich people (small/medium business owners, not oligarchs obviously) who started from a very poor family background. In fact, since absolute majority of the country was dirt poor in the 90's, everybody started from the same economic rung - wealth was just not a strong signal predicting success, compared to developed economies and even compared to present day Russia.

Is it possible to become a large corporation from scratch without government assistance or political upheavals?

Yes, it is possible, but you definitely need access to capital.
Both Volozh from Yandex and Durov from VK.com had sources of capital they could make use of to have the growth they initially have.
It seems that it is possible to acquire both government assistance and political upheavals if you manage to grow big fast.

So it's said, this would (and probably will) be a good PhD thesis for someone to tackle over the course of several years. You won't get anything like a comprehensive answer on a stack.
The general answer, however, is that perestroika meant the creation of a hybrid system in which private ownership and market models were being integrated into the socialist system. The way people gained these 'owner' position was likely a combination of party status, social influence, and socioeconomic power (noting that even from the early days of the USSR wealth and power divides still existed). Then when the USSR collapsed into a number of new and ostensibly Liberal republics, the transition gave people who were positioned correctly the opportunity to engage in unfettered capitalism, similar to the conditions in the US Industrial Age. And just like the Industrial Age, that meant fierce competition, monopolization, exploitation, and all the other practices that created commercial magnates, industrial barons, and other uber-power-players. The Russian Federation oligarchs have more or less the same origins as the Rockefellers, Vanderbilts, Schwabs, and Morgans of the US.

There were two groups in the post Soviet Union with good opportunities to start a viable business:

the management standing high in the hierarchy, directors and the like. Inevitably standing high in the hierarchy of Communist party as well.
various criminal structures with both force and money to do the things the way they wanted.

Huge industry decline after privatization may be tied to that means of production went into hands of people good in seizing the property but bad in doing a profitable business with it.
That explains how Putin came into power. In places like Baltic states there was not any better.


and 2) do not even have to separate. For example, in Yekaterinburg, Uralmash mob was/is a criminal structure around a communist industry giant.

